# Generate Bits (0,1) in random pattern with no repetition

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, numbers, fibonacci

I am writing a window based software based on .NET Framework 4.0. I have a requirement of generating random numbers using only bits (0 or 1). The pattern of generated random numbers should not be same continuously.

So for same I googled lot and found an article at [link](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibrab.html#specrabCALC).

This article explains generating patterns in the rabbit sequence. There is title "The first 2000 its of the rabbit sequence". But since I'm not purely tech guy from Maths background. So I'm finding it hard to understand and implement same in program.

Can anyone help me to implement the provided pattern algorithm in program so that the program can generate sequence of `0 1 0 1` in such way that there would be no repetition of bits (atleast upto 1000 bits).

Comment: That's not asking for a design pattern but for an algorithm, and a homework solution. What have you tried?

Comment: int myBit = new Random().Next(0, 2); Or you could have a look at the [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

Comment: [Guaranteed random number generator](http://xkcd.com/221/) ;)

Comment: @Nolonar - 4 is not a valid bit! ^_^

Comment: @Sam Sorry, fixed it :S

Comment: You're saying you want randomness of your bit pattern but at the same, have a sequence of `0 1 0 1` with no repetition of bits. That's not random.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Please don't misunderstand me. This is not a homework. It's a project for client. I need any sort of help or guidance for same.

Comment: @SimonBelanger The sequence 0 1 0 1 I mentioned was just for explaining my question point. Not mandatory to have that very same sequence.

Comment: "no repetition of bits" - that's tough. I mean `0`, `1`, `10` and that's it. `11` has repeated bits. But then again `10101010...` doesn't seem too random either.

Comment: @Corak I probably misunderstood what he's asking. It's not very clear either. CryptoServiceProvider would probably be a good start for him though (as Sam suggested)

Comment: @SimonBelanger - oh, I didn't mean your comment, I was quoting OP. ^_^; - Anyways, in these cases, one usually does not "generate" numbers on the fly. One generates a large enough set of unique values beforehand, randomly selects from that set and removes the selected value, then randomly selects the next one, removes that, and so on and so forth.